# Is it safe to keep the Asus notbook plugged in to AC power while working?

Tags: laptop, battery, asus-laptop

I sometimes work the whole day with the machine. at that time, I keep my laptop plugged in the the ac adapter and work with the machine. When im done, I remove it. People say its ok to do this because most of the laptops will auto turn off power to the battery if its full and direct them to the notebook. Is this true for Asus?

Comment: @Dennis Different manufacturers handle this in different ways. HP say it can and Asus sometimes say it can't. Thats why I specifically asked about Asus notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had my Asus laptop working on AC power with battery inserted almost all the time for 2 years now and it seems that battery is totally fine.

What's more, it may be worse for your battery to unplug the charger that to leave it plugged in, as its durability depends on the number of charge cycles. See [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/549925/does-depleting-the-battery-completely-do-damage-to-it/549939#549939).

Comment: It will surely depend on battery type. My battery still gives me about 4 hours of work, like when it was new.

Comment: Most people have the same battery type on their laptops these days: Lithium-Ion. I am sure if you take a look at the label on your battery it will say the same thing. It's great news that it still works well.

Comment: @gronostaj i just contacted Asus and they told me its not safe and uplug the power when the battery is charged!

Comment: @EApubs - you should post that as your answer so your question will close and your answer can help others that do not scower through the comments.

Comment: @CarlB Im not sure whether that answer is true because once I tried to ask it from HP... One representative told me its ok and the other told me its not. So im confused!

Comment: As listed [here](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries) "Li-ion does not need to be fully charged, as is the case with lead acid, nor is it desirable to do so. In fact, it is better not to fully charge, because high voltages stresses the battery. Choosing a lower voltage threshold, or eliminating the saturation charge altogether, prolongs battery life but this reduces the runtime. Since the consumer market promotes maximum runtime, these chargers go for maximum capacity rather than extended service life."